# Getting values using onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get 2 values from the link

```
<a onclick="rev()" href="track_path">
  <span id="name">username</span> - <span id="track">track_name</span>
</a>

<script>
function rev() {
  var username = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var track = document.getElementById("track").value;
  return alert (username);
}
</script>
```

But when alert comes, it writes UNDEFINED....What is wrong?

Comment: Because you're using `value` when you should be using `innerHTML`/`innerText`.

Comment: `.value` will get the string assigned to `value` attribute, not what you want here. Use `.textContent`. And `trim` it.

Comment: Don't post PHP if it's not related to question.

Comment: value is for input/select and textarea, not any other element.

Comment: @Tushar you mean value *property*

Comment: You are also missing semi-colon at the end of PHP Variable

Comment: @Mr.Developer They are optional at the end of expression. But PHP is not related here.

Answer (score 1):

`.value` is only use to take values of input, select or textarea fields. For html tags you need to use `.innerHTML`.

Change the script to this:

```
<script>
function rev(){
  var username = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
  var track = document.getElementById("track").innerHTML;
return alert (username);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Accodring to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) defintion:

> The value property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of
>   a text field.

So try using `innerHTML` or `textContent` instead:

```
  var username = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
```

or

```
  var username = document.getElementById("name").textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` refers to the value of an input element, while `innerHTML` refers to the HTML inside an element. This is an example :

```
<input type="text" value="foo" id="input">
<div id="div">foo</div>
```

In the first case you have an input, so you need to use `document.getElementById("input").value`, while in the second case you need to use `document.getElementById("div").innerHTML`.
Remember that if you have to get a value from an element in Javascript outside a function, it's better to use `window.onload` to make sure the elements are recognized by Javascript.
In your case, you must so use this script :

```
function rev() {
  var username = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
  var track = document.getElementById("track").innerHTML;
  return alert (username);
}
```